# How to automate sendGrid account creation with ARM template?

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a deployment with many azure services in it along with SendGrid using ARM template. When I create sendGrid account using UX, it asks to create the API key from its official site manually. How do I automate this using ARM template?